# NextJS Changes Route but Renders Same Page without CSS

Tags: next.js, routes

Here's a website where this happens: [here](https://landlord.bg)

The index page is loaded.

Then you press any of the navigation links, for example, the last one.

The route changes; however, NextJS renders the same index page without the CSS.

The result is a dismal user experience.

What can I do to solve this?

---

EDIT:
I found the culprit.

I recently installed Facebook Chat.

I created this component:

```
import Script from 'next/script';

export const FacebookChat = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.hostname.includes('localhost')) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <div id="fb-customer-chat" className="fb-customerchat">
            </div>
            <Script
                id="facebook-messenger"
                strategy="afterInteractive"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
    var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
    chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v15.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  `,
                }} />
        </>
    )
}
```

And then I use it in `index.js` like this:

`<FacebookChat />`

After removing it, it works fine.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: It is weird as it works fine after a quick refresh. Could you share more details or give a sample code of your header routing ?

Comment: @IGnyte I've added an update. The issue was the code above.

Ideally, I'd like to have the chat available, but if it's causing this issue, I'll have to rethink it.